# How to access files of folder like Downloads & DCIM without letting user choose or interact in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-external-storage, android-storage

Since methods like `getExternalStorageDirectory() , getExternalStoragePublic()` are deprecated so how can i access the files of folders like DCIM , DOWNLOADS without letting user to choose or interact like any gallery app opens all images available on device or like any file manager app shows files of Directories . How can i achieve that ?

Comment: That depends. You have full access to those folders to create and write your files there. If you wanna list and read files you will only see the files of your app and media files. So tell your use case. And just use these deprecated functions.

Answer (score 0):

MediaStore is the new and best practice for any storage related stuff.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore